# MS access 2007, Single form to multiple tables

Tags: database, ms-access-2007, multiple-tables

i want to work on a form, here i will enter the data into text fields and this will be updated into a table as a new entry. Now out of the fields available iwant few of them to be stored into another table. so its like saving form data into multiple tables. I searched in many places but cudnt find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use a form and a subform. Table1 is bound to form and Table2 is bound to subform.

Comment: Is it just me, or are about half the answers you've given in the last week essentially "create a form and a subform"? This is not a flaw in your answers, as each time, you are quite correct to suggest it, but it just seems that recently there are a whole bunch of questions from newbies who haven't ever learned the basics of Access.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Happens every Autumn/Winter, I reckon. :)

Comment: I don't recall it in past seasons, though.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Happened a lot on Tek-Tips.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution...i dont want to go for another form though...but i figured out a way..for the 2nd table i introduced a button and on click of the event wrote a vb code such that it will look for ID field of type autonumber(introduced for the sake of searching row) and used dlookup with a criteria expression to find out the row in 2nd table n used a insert statement...this worked...thanks for the response, appreciate it...